# Howto get better Error messages for Symfony 3 Authentication with EntityRepository

Tags: authentication, entity, symfony

Hi I'm loading users from a database. ( without using FOSUserBundle or Grant )
I'm using the Entity provider method from the [Symfony 3 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html)
but I ran into a problem. Everything works just fine, I can login but when I try to login with a wrong username I get this rather undescriptive error

> Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem.

It's unclear for the developer and raises total panic for a normal user, so I have to find a way to replace this with something more meangingfull.

I tried to throw a UserNameNotFoundException or BadCredentialsException in my UserRepostory, it has no effect.

Is there a way I can improve this or should I abandon this method and use a UserProvider and service approach ?

PS : I also would like to improve the BadCrentials message.

The UserRepository :

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/UserRepository.php

namespace AppBundle\Entity ;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface ;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface ;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException ;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository ;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserLoaderInterface {

public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{

        $user = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.username = :username OR u.email = :email')
            ->setParameter('username', $username)
            ->setParameter('email', $username)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();


        if($user === null){
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("You provided a wrong username");
        }

        return $user;
    }
}
?>
```

In security.yml :

```
ordinary_users
  entity:
       class: AppBundle:OrdinaryUser
```

The controller :

```
class securityController extends Controller {
/**
* @Route("/account/signin", name="signin_form")
* @Template("AppBundle:security:signin.html.twig")
*/
public function signinAction(Request $request)
{
    $this->get('logger')->info("called secureLoginAction");
    $session = $request->getSession();
    //gets the login error is there is one

    if($request->attributes->get(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)){
        $error = $request->attributes->get(
            Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR
        );
    } else {
        $error = $session->get(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        $session->remove(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }

    return array(
        'last_username' => $session->get(Security::LAST_USERNAME),
        'error' => $error
    );
}

... goes on nothing special all like in the example.
```

I don't include the rather long OrdinaryUser entity, but is a standard AdvancedUserInterface implementation.

So how do i fix this ? 
( After it's fixed I would like to translate it to a ajax login, but that's for later. )

Comment: Start by adding  hide_user_not_found:  false  (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#full-default-configuration) under security.  This will distinguish when a user is not found though doing so can be considered a security issue.

Comment: Okay, been away for some time, I will try it.

Comment: I'm busy with some other work, keep you posted